# Numpy: Get rectangle area just the size of mask

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

**I have an image and a mask. Both are numpy array.** I get the mask through GraphSegmentation (cv2.ximgproc.segmentation), so the area isn't rectangle, but not divided. I'd like to get a rectangle just the size of masked area, but I don't know the efficient way.

> In other words, unmasked pixels are value of 0 and masked pixels are value over 0, so I want to get a rectangle where...

- **top** = the smallest index of axis 0 whose value > 0
- **bottom** = the largest index of axis 0 whose value > 0
- **left** = the smallest index axis 1 whose value > 0
- **right** = the largest index axis 1 whose value > 0
- **image** = src[top : bottom, left : right]

**My code is below**

```
segmentation = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createGraphSegmentation()
src = cv2.imread('image_file')
segment = segmentation.processImage(src)
for i in range(np.max(segment)):
    dst = np.array(src)
    dst[segment != i] = 0
    cv2.imwrite('output_file', dst)
```

Comment: Get the `boundingRect` of your non-zero pixels

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you prefer pure Numpy, you can achieve this using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid):

```
i, j = np.where(mask)
indices = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min(i), max(i) + 1),
                      np.arange(min(j), max(j) + 1),
                      indexing='ij')
sub_image = image[indices]
```

`np.where` returns a tuple of arrays specifying, pairwise, the indices in each axis for each non-zero element of `mask`.  We then create arrays of all the row and column indices we will want using `np.arange`, and use `np.meshgrid` to generate two grid-shaped arrays that index the part of the image we're interested in.  Note that we specify matrix-style indexing using `index='ij'` to avoid having to transpose the result (the default is Cartesian-style indexing).

Essentially, `meshgrid` constructs `indices` so that:

```
image[indices][a, b] == image[indices[0][a, b], indices[1][a, b]]
```

## Example

Start with the following:

```
>>> image = np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3))
>>> image
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Let's say we want to extract the `[[3,4],[6,7]]` sub-matrix, which is the bounding rectangle for the the following mask:

```
>>> mask = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]])
>>> mask
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Then, applying the above method:

```
>>> i, j = np.where(mask)
>>> indices = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min(i), max(i) + 1), np.arange(min(j), max(j) + 1), indexing='ij')
>>> image[indices]
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 7]])
```

Here, `indices[0]` is a matrix of row indices, while `indices[1]` is the corresponding matrix of column indices:

```
>>> indices[0]
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
>>> indices[1]
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 5):

I think using `np.amax` and `np.amin` and cropping the image is much faster.

```
i, j = np.where(mask)
indices = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min(i), max(i) + 1),
              np.arange(min(j), max(j) + 1),
              indexing='ij')
sub_image = image[indices]
```

Time taken: 50 msec

```
where = np.array(np.where(mask))

x1, y1 = np.amin(where, axis=1)
x2, y2 = np.amax(where, axis=1)
sub_image = image[x1:(x2+1), y1:(y2+1)]
```

Time taken: 5.6 msec

Comment: should add +1 to `x2` and `y2`, i.e. sub_image = image[x1:x2+1, y1:y2+1] as `x2` and `y2` should be included.

Answer (score 5):

I don't get Hans's results when running the two methods (using NumPy 1.18.5). In any case, there is a much more efficient method, where you take the arg-max along each dimension

```py
i, j = np.where(mask)
y, x = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(min(i), max(i) + 1),
    np.arange(min(j), max(j) + 1),
    indexing="ij",
)
```

Took 38 ms

```py
where = np.array(np.where(mask))
y1, x1 = np.amin(where, axis=1)
y2, x2 = np.amax(where, axis=1) + 1
sub_image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Took 35 ms

```py
maskx = np.any(mask, axis=0)
masky = np.any(mask, axis=1)
x1 = np.argmax(maskx)
y1 = np.argmax(masky)
x2 = len(maskx) - np.argmax(maskx[::-1])
y2 = len(masky) - np.argmax(masky[::-1])
sub_image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Took 2 ms

[Timings script](https://gist.github.com/EpicWink/b672fdc3b083126825767b70e0c5d6c1)